# How do I automatically close the old version of a C# program when a user upgrades to the new?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, upgrade

Say my users are using version 1.0 of a program, and they decide to upgrade to version 2.0. They may not think to close the old version before they start the installation of the newer version.

I use Tarma InstallMate 9 to create installs. How do I automatically close the old version of my .NET program (written in C#) during the upgrade to the latest version?

Is this something I would code inside the program, or something I would add to the installer? If the latter, how would I get InstallMate to communicate with the program to allow it to be terminated?

What are the best practices in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem specific to the install software you are using, in this case Tarma Installmate 9. Rather than this being a .NET issue you need to find whether or not there are any settings in Tarma Installmate to kill processes.

Since you know the process name I would suggest killing it inside your C# application, but since you presumably have not got the ability to add your own code inside the installer you have no other option.

Comment: Did you mean to say: "I **wouldn't usually** suggest killing it inside your C# application" as that means the rest of the sentence will make sense.